# WebApplicationInitializer don't work in springboot

Tags: java

My WebConfig code,it implements the WebApplicationInitializer

```java
public class WebConfig implements WebApplicationInitializer {
    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        System.out.println("on startup");
    }
}
```

My MyApplication code

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

My pom.xml

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

But I can't see the "on startup" in the console. Anyone can help me ?thanks.And I don't want to say a lot,but the stackoverflow look like to prenvent me to post the question....

Answer (score 0):

> This was actually an intentional design decision. The search algorithm
> used by the containers was problematic. It also causes problems when
> you want to develop an executable WAR as you often want a
> javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer for the WAR that is not
> executed when you run java -jar.
>
> See the
> org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.ServletContextInitializer
> for an option that works with Spring Beans.

-- https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/321#issuecomment-34353800

also see https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/522